# gurobipy: update tupledict implementation

Tags: python, cython, gurobi

I am using `tupledict` from `gurobipy` and I really like the `select` function. However it is limited to values and not conditioanl expressions.

My tupledict of variables contains as a key a tuple `(r,t)` where `r` is an object that stands for route and has 2 main attributes nodes and edges (for simplicity I just mention these two), and `t` is an integer representing the time period. I am doing a branch and price algorithm and I have to branch on the number of visits to a node, meaning that I will have to iterate over my`tupledict` of variables to see whether a route `r` contains a node or not. Other times I have to check whether a route contains an edge. These iterations are quite expensive, and I was wondering if it is possible to know how the `select` method is built as it is quite fast when selecting a `t` for instance.
I am willing to write my own `tupledict` class using cython and write functions like `select` for each of the branching rules I have, however I do not seem to find the implementation of `tupledict`. I hope it is not a "secret".

Answer (score 0):

[gurobipy.tuplelist](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_tuplelist.html) and [gurobipy.tupledict](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_tupledict.html) were created for the common optimization model structure where you want a subset elements that match on one tuple. The canonical use case is flow conservation constraints for a network flow model: you want all the arcs incident to a node. Specifically, you want all (directed) arcs (i,j) and (j,k) for a fixed j.

What you describe is a bit different: you want to find (r,t) where route r contains node j. This isn't about matching a specific value: this requires understanding the structure of the route object.

tl;dr: This isn't supported by gurobipy.tuplelist, but you can build your own index from j to r using something like a dictionary of lists.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. yes I understand it is not supported, however, I am wondering how is the tupledict implemented as I want to adapt it to my situation. I believe if I want to follow your suggestion then I need to create 3 dicts of lists for nodes j, edges, and the sink node and keeping them updated will be costly (especially for the edges) and not as efficient as if I modify the implementation of select. Would it be possible to give me hints on what is done under the hood in select?